# React Native - Text on top of my touchables

Tags: react-native

Trying to make my first app and learn a bit about coding and react and react native. I started making this mtg life counter and ran into a problem that the touchables are under some text and therefore cannot be pressed. Is there a simple way around this?

I would want the upper half of the number also register + to life and the lower part to - life. It currently kind of works on mobile, but the touchable part is too small.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';

const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
var opponentColor = 'green'
var playerColor = 'red'

export default function App() {

  const [playerLife, setplayerLife] = useState(20);
  const [opponentLife, setOpponentLife] = useState(20);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.rivi}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress ={() => setplayerLife(playerLife - 1)}>
        <View style={styles.sideContainerOpponent}>
          <Text>Mana -</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress ={() => setOpponentLife(opponentLife - 1)}>
          <View style={styles.midContainerOpponent}>
            <Text>Vihu -</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View style={styles.sideContainerOpponent}>
          <Text>Tyhjä</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rivi}>
        <View style={styles.sideContainerOpponent}>
          <Text>Mana +</Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress ={() => setOpponentLife(opponentLife + 1)}>
          <View style={styles.midContainerOpponent}>
            <Text>Vihu +</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View style={styles.sideContainerOpponent}>
          <Text>Tyhjä</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.rivi}>
        <View style={styles.sideContainerPlayer}>
          <Text>Tyhjä</Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress ={() => setplayerLife(playerLife + 1)}>
          <View style={styles.midContainerPlayer}>
            {/* <Text>Life +</Text> */}
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View style={styles.sideContainerPlayer}>
          <Text>Mana +</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rivi}>
        <View style={styles.sideContainerPlayer}>
          <Text>Tyhjä </Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress ={() => setplayerLife(playerLife - 1)}>
          <View style={styles.midContainerPlayer}>
            <Text>Life -</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View style={styles.sideContainerPlayer}>
          <Text>Mana -</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.pelaaja1}>
        <Text style={styles.lifeCounterPlayer}>
        {playerLife}
      </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.pelaaja2}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.lifeCounterOpponent}>
          {opponentLife}
      </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View >


  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rivi: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    alignContent: 'stretch',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  sideContainerOpponent: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: opponentColor,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  midContainerOpponent: {
    flex: 3,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  sideContainerPlayer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: playerColor,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  midContainerPlayer: {
    flex: 3,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  pelaaja1: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: windowHeight / 2,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  pelaaja2: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: windowHeight / 2,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  lifeCounterPlayer: {
    fontSize: windowHeight / 4,
  },
  lifeCounterOpponent: {
    fontSize: windowHeight / 4,
    transform: [{ rotate: '180deg' }]
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi @imppu, when adding React Native code, especially when using Expo, you can take advantage of the Snack website. I created a snack with your code here: https://snack.expo.io/yBmxTWE0j 
You can go ahead and put that link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to bring the View of your TouchableWithoutFeedback to the front on the z axis with zIndex and set it e.g. to 100. And you should remove the backgroundColor from the view or set the alpha of the backgroundColor that you can look thru.

Like this you can touch always your "+" and "-" TouchableWithoutFeedback

```
midContainerOpponent: {
    flex: 3,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    zIndex: 100
    
  }
```

But like the the documentation said, use it only if you have a very good reason, cause all elements that respond to press should have a visual feedback when touched.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback

You can use e.g. [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity) (Ios / Android) or[TouchableNativeFeedback](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablenativefeedback) (Android)

Comment: The problem is that the text that shows the life total of the player is on top of the touchable I want to press and blocks it. I'm using absolute in the positioning as I want the text to be in half on top of each button, but I would like to still to be able to press them.

Comment: You can set the zIndex: 100 in your midContainerOpponent and also remove the backgroundColor. Now the midContainerOpponent is above your "pelaaja1"

Comment: Got it to work by adding the zIndex and removing the background. But then I need to get to color the box under the number somehow. I tried adding the backround to 'rivi' but that broke it again. Even when I did put zIndex for all the stuff that stack there. I want to be able to change the backround color eventually. The top half being one color and bottom half another color.

Comment: You can add to your "pelaaja1" and "pelaaja2" style e.g. a backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    zIndex: -1 . Or if you want it splitted arrange for e.g. two Views under ( zIndex: -1) in your "Pelaajas" Views and set your backgroundColors.

Comment: Thank you! I will get hang of this step by step.

Answer (score 0):

There is a component called `Pressable`, you can read about it in the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable). This component is currently the best one to use for anything "button-like". One big advantage of `Pressable` is that it's very easy to style.

You can replace your `TouchableWithoutFeedback` with this component like this:

```
<Pressable onPress ={() => setplayerLife(playerLife - 1)} style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <View style={styles.sideContainerOpponent}>
   <Text>Mana -</Text>
  </View>
</Pressable>
```

I created a Snack where I used the above code for the first button and it seems to be working nicely: https://snack.expo.io/lRq8f_o4V

P.S.
My son is a big fan of MTG :) I think this app is a great idea and will be useful!